ECS with EC2, container instances not showing up in ecs cluster
we are using ECS with EC2. In the capacity provider (auto scaling group), we see 8 instances. 4 of them gradually showed up on the ECS cluster as container instances, while the other 4 just don't show up, even after one hour.
How could this be? We have pending tasks to be deployed, and the container instances are just not ready.
Thanks in advance.

The first thing I would check is if the EC2 instances in certain VPC subnets work, wile the EC2 instances in other VPC subnets don't work. This sounds like an issue where the EC2 instances don't have a network route to the ECS service API because some of them are in a private subnet or something.

thank you @MarkB. The ec2 instances are created through the launch template by aws, they should be in the same VPC/Subnets

Each EC2 instance can only be in a single subnet. You give the launch template a list of subnets to deploy to, and it will deploy different instances to different subnets for high-availability and fault-tolerance purposes. If one of those subnets isn't configured correctly, then the instances that get randomly assigned to that subnet could exhibit the issue you are encountering.

the subnets are not having any problems, they are in use for a long time.

You should ssh into one of the EC2 instances that isn't working, and verify it has Internet access, or at least ECS API access if you have a VPC endpoint for ECS configured on the VPC.

Do you have AmazonECSManaged tag =true on every instance?
